# Extend and Round active and inactive Slider Track in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, slider

How can I extend the Inactive and Active track of the Slider class, so that it always "hugs" the thumb?

These images illustrate my intentions:
[Active Track around Thumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ycXH.png)
[Inactive Track extended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t6H8.png)

My approach was to create a `CustomTrackShape` and put it in the `trackShape:` property of `sliderTheme`.
I've tried countless examples provided by chatGPT which all failed. Like this:

```
class CustomTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double? trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    final double trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight!) / 2;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset offset, {
        required RenderBox parentBox,
        required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
        Animation<double>? enableAnimation = const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1.0),
        required TextDirection textDirection,
        bool isDiscrete = false,
        bool isEnabled = false,
      }) {
    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(parentBox: parentBox, offset: offset, sliderTheme: sliderTheme);

    final ColorTween activeTrackColorTween = ColorTween(begin: sliderTheme.disabledActiveTrackColor, end: sliderTheme.activeTrackColor);
    final ColorTween inactiveTrackColorTween = ColorTween(begin: sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTrackColor, end: sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor);

    final Paint activePaint = Paint()..color = activeTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation!)!;
    final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()..color = inactiveTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)!;

    // Calculate the corner radius as half of the track height
    final double radius = trackRect.height / 2;

    // Draw the active track
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromPoints(
          Offset(trackRect.left, trackRect.center.dy - trackRect.height / 4),
          Offset(trackRect.right, trackRect.center.dy + trackRect.height / 4),
        ),
        Radius.circular(radius),
      ),
      activePaint,
    );

    // Draw the inactive track
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromPoints(
          Offset(trackRect.left, trackRect.center.dy - trackRect.height / 4),
          Offset(trackRect.right, trackRect.center.dy + trackRect.height / 4),
        ),
        Radius.circular(radius),
      ),
      inactivePaint,
    );
  }
}
```

The error message is like this:

```
lib/main.dart:75:8: Error: The method 'CustomTrackShape.paint' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'SliderTrackShape.paint'.
  void paint(
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider_theme.dart:1090:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('paint').
  void paint(
       ^
lib/main.dart:75:8: Error: The method 'CustomTrackShape.paint' doesn't have the named parameter 'secondaryOffset' of overridden method 'SliderTrackShape.paint'.
  void paint(
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/slider_theme.dart:1090:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('paint').
  void paint(
       ^
```

I expected it to compile in the first place and then customising the actual shapes.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Nope @TusharPatel